Excel trailing zeros
Given this formula in excel =TEXT(ROUND(R22,C13),"0.00")
How do I make so that "0.00" is calculated automatically depending on the number of digits inputted in C13.
Ex1
C13 = 3
and R22 = 0.4023
I want it my cell to = 0.402
Ex2
C13=2
R21 = 0.400
I want my cell to show 0.40
How do I do this so the trailing 0s are automatically calculated and I dont have to mention the number of 0's I want for each cell every time.

=TEXT(ROUND(R22,$C$13), "0." & REPT("0",$C$13))
update
but as Atmo pointed out,
`=TEXT(R22, "0." & REPT("0",$C$13))`

would suffice.

I know this part comes from OP's question but there is no need to ROUND the figure before turning it into a formatted string.  More precisely, ROUNDDOWN or ROUNDUP would have an impact on the result but not ROUND: the format will already round to the nearest floating-point with $C$13 decimal places.

Yes, of course - thanks for 'point'ing out ;)
